# How do I make a website totally untrackable back to me, Anonymous?

Tags: google, local-seo

I need to create a website that is totally untraceable back to me, even from the police. The reason is that there is some shady behavior by the police and I am afraid of any reactions from them toward me or my family. How easy is it to do this? Is it even possible??

Comment: sounds legit...

Answer (score 1):

Taking this question at face value, and since privacy is a growing concern...

You would likely want to use an [anonymizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymizer) so that any signups and logins to servers would be done anonymously through a [proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). Server logs might still be obtainable, but more difficult if the servers are located in another country, particularly if they're [daisy chained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_topology#Daisy_chain) as well. You can do a Google search for online anonymizer services and software that might provide this.

If you need a unique domain for the website, you can use a "Domain Privacy" option during registration, preferably with a registrar located in another country as well. See this question for more on that: [Concerns regarding registering a domain name with a home address](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49766/concerns-regarding-registering-a-domain-name-with-a-home-address/49768#49768) Otherwise, a user account at a free or shared web hosting provider might suffice.

Keep in mind that tracking could still be accomplished with the proper resources, authority, and cooperation of the server operators.

Lastly, if your name really is "Fred", you might not want to use that :-)

Comment: Good points.  Adding on that if he is going to buy a domain... using an untraceable money source (Green dot prepaid credit card, bitcoin) might be a good idea as well.  However, using something like Wordpress.com, Tumblr, Blogger, or a free web hosting could leave money out of the picture altogether

Comment: Domain privacy does not work with law enforcement authorities. They can see all of it. You can fake the address but remember your payment details  will already have been recorded.

Comment: @John For a registrar in another country? Any references for that?