# whois — Can I use a general delivery (poste restante) address?

Tags: whois, icann

As far as I know, ICANN wants every domain owner to put their contact information into the WHOIS database. I'm fine with revealing my real name, but having to submit the address where I live seems like a privacy killer to me. Wouldn't ICANN be satisfied with a [general delivery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poste_restante) address? Do they actually contact people by paper mail without a prior notice?

*P. S.*
Of course, I know about the existence of WHOIS privacy services. Let's assume I don't want to use one for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

ICANN requirements passed along registries, registrars and finally the registrant are that you can be contacted at the address given, in the (honestly never occuring) case someone sends you a letter there.

If your address accepts mail for you that you can collect, you fulfill the requirements.

See https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/faqs-f0-2012-02-25-en : email is clearly more important.
The "code of conduct" is however ICANN "Registrants' Benefits and Responsibilities" at https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/benefits-2013-09-16-en that states you need to provide acurate information.

Comment: However, several domain "Registries" do not permit the use the PO Box style postal addresses. See this related question: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49766/concerns-regarding-registering-a-domain-name-with-a-home-address

Comment: @MrWhite What you say in the other question as comments is about ccTLDs, here we speak about gTLDs because only those are contracted with ICANN. But of course, as a general rule, one has to read the contract he signs carefully, and each registry can have specific rules.

Comment: My comment on the other question isn't necessarily restricted to ccTLDs. All gTLDs are governed by a Registry that could impose further restrictions - as you've just mentioned in your comment: "each registry can have specific rules".

Comment: But your examples were all ccTLDs...

Comment: Exactly, they are just some "examples" (which just so happen to be ccTLDs). It's not a comprehensive list.

Comment: And yet the question here is about **ICANN** requirements... I will stop here trying to explain the fine difference.

Comment: Whilst the OP mentions ICANN, they are also querying with respect to actually registering a domain. Yes, they might satisfy the requirements of ICANN, but that doesn't necessarily they will still be able to use a _general delivery address_ when registering the domain if the requirements of the Registry are not met. That's all I'm saying, I'm not disagreeing with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like what we'd call in the US, a PO Box, and that would satisfy the ICANN requirement.  As long as you can be reached using the contact information, it is considered valid.

Comment: Actually, Poste Restante and PO Boxes are two different things.  Poste Restante is typically used by travellers - I know I will be in a city on a few weeks, I tell people they can mail me c/- Poste Restante, City.  The main post office will hold the mail for collection, generally for up to 2 months.  I suspect that in the days of email and messaging the use has fallen way off.